# hg push --new-branch going to wrong branch

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I made a new bug fix branch from a mybranch but it somehow seems to want to push it to another branch after i've committed and made the edits..

So why is my push --new-branch going to a wrong branch (from which i did not made the fix branch)

Comment: Post in the result of `hg log --graph -l 10`, your description is cryptic.

Answer (score -1):

(**Edited**)

to check if you create a new branch in your local repository, you can use command:

```
$> hg branches
```

to change branch in your local repository, you can use:

```
$> hg branch <branch_name>
```

Comment: No. `hg push --new-branch` does not create another branch, it only allows the push IF a new branch has been created in the local commits.

Comment: -1, because pushing without parameters will not even work. Since a new branch has been created, it will always abort without the --new-branch.

Comment: Edited following comments

Comment: Although what you say is true, it absolutely does not answer the question... And by the way, you can also add `hg branch` to identify the current branch, as this might actually bring some clue as to where its commit is. Otherwise, `hg branches` will list all of them, even the wrong branch, which may not come from him anyway, and what is the point of changing branch if the commit is already done?